# Excel 2013 auto formatting numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I am entering `1044372000263084` into a cell in Excel 2013. When I hit enter the cell is changing to `1.04437E + 15` . The bar above the table shows `104437200063080`.

Why is it changing and how can I make it stop?

Comment: Format an empty cell as text. Right click on the cell, select Format Cells, set the format to Text. Take a long number like 1240800388917 and paste it in to the text formatted cell. Now, the cell is displayed as a string and not in scientific notation.The results remaining in scientific notation even though the cell is formatted as text just seems broken to me. I've seen suggested work-arounds like: use CSV import and set the format to text, add a space character to the beginning of each numeric string, and others.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells where you are going to input, hit Control + 1 to format cells, select "Number" under the Number tab (optionally, set Decimal places to zero), hit OK. Now, long numbers entered into the cells just formatted will appear without scientific notation.

Comment: This will fail since the number precision in Excel is limited to 15 digits.  So while it won't be scientific notation, the actual value will go from 1044372000263084  to 1044372000263080.

Comment: Found a solution: Format an empty cell as text. Right click on the cell, select Format Cells, set the format to Text. Take a long number like 1240800388917 and paste it in to the text formatted cell. Now, the cell is displayed as a string and not in scientific notation.The results remaining in scientific notation even though the cell is formatted as text just seems broken to me. I've seen suggested work-arounds like: use CSV import and set the format to text, add a space character to the beginning of each numeric string, and others.

Answer (score 0):

Excel will treat the content aimed for a cell as TEXT,
if the data to go into that cell has a single quote as first character.
`="The char: "&CHAR(39)` in a cell will show that character.

`=VALUE(ADDRESS)` will allow you to use the number.